# ports to open to access samba share

Tags: centos, iptables, samba, selinux

When I turn off my iptables service, I can successfully list my samba shares.
But when I turn it back on, I cannot access them at all.

Also, my SELINUX is set to permissive

Here is my current iptables configuration:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two reject rules are in the wrong place. As currently written, these rules will only let traffic through on port 22.

The "catch all" reject rules need to go after all of the accept rules.